# Linking separate UIScrollBar to ScrollPane in Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe, scrollbar, scrollpane

I'm needing a short scrollbar to be placed apart from its corresponding and longer scrollpane, but am receiving the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property maxScrollH not found on
fl.containers.ScrollPane and there is no default value.
at fl.controls::UIScrollBar/updateScrollTargetProperties()
at fl.controls::UIScrollBar/draw()
at fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher()
```

Searching, I can't find a way to access maxScrollH to begin fixing the problem. Trying to access the property my usual way...

```
ScrollPane_instance.maxScrollH = 1440;
```

... produces a different error:

```
Symbol 'Gllryscrn_mclp', Layer 'Gallery', Frame 1, Line 3, Column 19    1119:
Access of possibly undefined property maxScrollH through a reference with 
static type fl.containers:ScrollPane.
```

I'm briefly self-taught, so apologise for any rookie oversights.

Comment: We really need some more code to help you. BTW: Are you avoiding the Flex Components (Spark or MX) on purpose? You could take a look at the Scroller-Component: http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/index.html

Comment: Very sorry, thought I'd follow up. I'm not familiar with Flex, but the main issue was I wasn't happy with the degree of customisation with the regular UIscrollbar, so created a second scrollpane to function as one instead, simply making the percentage scrolled of the first equal the percentage of the second. A couple more features to add, such as clicking to "jump" to that point, but happy with the functionality overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I'd follow up, in case anyone else had a similar problem. I wasn't happy with the degree of customisation of the regular UIscrollbar, so created a second scrollpane to function as a scrollbar instead. I just made the percentage scrolled of the first equal the percentage of the second and vice versa.